# Data driven unit test in combination with LocalDB not working in VSTS

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, data-driven-tests

I have a problem running data driven unit tests (MSTest) in VSTS. My situation is the following:
In my C# solution I have a MSTest-test project which contains three test classes that contain data driven test methods.
These methods used to work with an attached MDF-file as data source, but for reasons of maintainability I added a database-project to my solution which contains the scripts to create and fill a database with my test data.

The test-project also contains an initialize method (marked with the `AssemblyInitialize` attribute) which deploys the dacpac from the database-project) to a LocalDB-instance. For this deployment I use the `Microsoft.SqlServer.DACFx` NuGet-package.

The data driven test methods all use the following connection string 
    `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Enkoni_Validation_Tests;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30`
The problem is that this solution workes locally without any problems, but when I trigger a build on VSTS, most of the tests run fine, but one test class constantly failes with the message

> "The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. (...) Error details: Cannot open database "Enkoni_Validation_Tests" requested by the login. The login failed."

The testmethods in the other two classes run without any problems. Since all three test classes are part of the same project, I assume the initialization (the deployment of the DacPac) runs without problems. 
Has anyone experienced a similar problem or does anyone know how to solve this?

Edit (added some additional information): the build runs on a hosted build agent and it's always the same test that fails. I have considered that maybe there is some sort of limitation on how many connections can be made to the LocalDB database, but I can't find any information that supports this theory. And since all my tests run sequential, I also don't expect that there are many (or even more than one) connections.

Comment: Does this error always occur and only occur on that test class? Does the test run on the hosted build agent or your on-premise build agent?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added some additional information in my original post

Comment: Is the failed test class executed in the last? Have you tried to execute it first?

Comment: I've disabled all other unit tests except for the one test that caused the problems. Even then, the same error occurs

Comment: After trying several different possible solutions, like tweaking the connection strings and time outs, I've decided to switch to XML-files as datasource. The have the same maintainability and transparency but with higher reliability